# Meaning/significance of modulo operation in definition of transversal

Tags: group-theory

I'm currently working through a diploma thesis on algorithms regarding permutation groups ([T. Rehn "Fundamental Permutation Group Algorithms for Symmetry Computation", University of Magdeburg (2010)](http://www.math.uni-rostock.de/%7Erehn/docs/diploma-thesis-cs-rehn.pdf)).

In this work some basic concepts of group theory are defined and there is one definition in there that I have some trouble completely grasping. Namely the definition of a `transversal`.

After having introduced the concept of a `coset` it is stated that a group $G$ is partitioned by its cosets $gH$ for $g \in G$ and $H \le G$. It is then said that

> Thus it makes sense to define a right (left) transversal U ⊆ G for G modulo H as a set containing exactly one representative of every H-right (left) coset of G, including the identity

The definition of a transversal that I can find on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transversal_(combinatorics)) is

> In mathematics, particularly in combinatorics, given a family of sets, here called a collection C, a transversal [...] is a set containing exactly one element from each member of the collection. When the sets of the collection are mutually disjoint, each element of the transversal corresponds to exactly one member of C (the set it is a member of).

Since the cosets of a group are always either identical or disjoint, the set of cosets should only contain distinct and thus disjoint cosets, which should make the Wikipedia definition applicable here.

Now, the point that I fail to understand is why Mr. Rehn includes a modulo operation in his definition for a transversal. Why is the transversal not described as simply $U \subseteq G$ but instead the suffix "for G modulo H" is added?

What is the exact meaning of this addendum? To my (ad hoc) understanding "G modulo H" would describe the set of all elements that are in $G$ but are not in $H$. So essentially this appears to be identical to speaking of a set $S$ that is defined as $S = G - H$ (difference of sets).

Comment: For $H\le G$, the cosets of $H$ in $G$ are precisely the equivalence classes of the equivalence relation in $G$ defined by $x\sim y\iff xy^{-1}\in H$, usually referred to as "$G$ modulo $H$".

Comment: You have an incorrect understanding of the meaning of "modulo" in this context. Your understanding of the definition seems to be complete and accurate - it corresponds exactly to the Wikipedia definition - and you will loose nothing by just ignoring the phrase "$G$ modulo $H$". If you are interested, in the context of abstract groups, the word "modulo" used like this just means "in the cosets of $G$ with respect to $H$"

Comment: Ah okay, I see! Is there any intuitive explanation for why the term "modulo" is used like this here? Anyway, if any of you writes an actual answer stating that the issue here is due to an incorrect interpretation of what "modulo" actually means, I'll gladly accept that answer.

Comment: I believe that's because it mimics what happen with the integers modulo $n$: two integers $x,y$ are congruent modulo $n$ iff $x-y\in n\Bbb Z$, namely iff their difference is a multiple of $n$.  And "$x-y$" is just the additive version of the multiplicative "$xy^{-1}$", which is preferred for a general abstract group $G$ (with a subgroup $H$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrating my answer from the comments:

You have an incorrect understanding of the meaning of "modulo" in this context. Your understanding of the definition seems to be complete and accurate - it corresponds exactly to the Wikipedia definition - and you will loose nothing by just ignoring the phrase "G modulo H". If you are interested, in the context of abstract groups, the word "modulo" used like this just means "in the cosets of G with respect to H"

The intuition for the term "modulo" comes, as @fitzcarraldo rightly says from modular arithmetic, where two integers $x$ and $y$ are equal modulo $n$ if $x-y$ is a multiple of $n$. Reinterpreted in the langrage of groups, the cosets of $n\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ are exactly the sets of numbers which are equal modulo $n$.